# Why kademlia for p2p?

Tags: peers, p2p

It seems pointless to me. I looked at the actual implementation. Kademila is used to discover peers, but there is no gained benefits. As when the node connects to peers, it simply just grab from the peers group. Kademila has no benefit? Correct me if im wrong

Comment: not an expert, but from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kademlia) `Kademlia contacts only O(log(n)) nodes during the search out of a total of n nodes in the system`. from my understanding, the "benefit", is the SPEED at which it can discover those peers.

Comment: speed at which it can discover "those" peers. what are "those" peers in your context? all full nodes are identical so what is the need for "those" peers? thx

Comment: in this context, when you DON'T have full peers and need to find the peer(s) with the data that you want. similar to sharding I guess. from my understanding, the address/hash acts like a locator, so with Kademlia you NEVER have to search the entire space to find your data (never more than half, but usually much less??). again, i'm not that familiar, just offering some info, as I'm also looking for a better understanding

Comment: thank you @nyusternie I realized this is a typical cargo cult engineering. they did not realize that they did not need kademlia. anyways, you looking for blockchain developer job? I am hiring.

Comment: you may need a 2nd opinion on some of that info lol. i'm always interested in open-source projects, message me

Answer (score 1):

@user2584960: I agree and am confused as to the point Kademlia being used in Ethereum. If you aren't querying for content then what are you querying?

I believe Ethereum's use of Kademlia is like looking up a phone number in a phonebook and using the phone number as the query key. Alternatively, if you were to maintain metrics for each peer, then perhaps you could query each node's Kademlia table for nodes that satisfy the particular metrics you are interested in.

@nyusternie:

Ethereum's Kademlia implementation is only for peer discovery. Therefore, you aren't querying for content. Therefore, what the heck are you querying?